# Specific heat of a panel composed of layers of different materials

Tags: thermodynamics

Given a panel composed of layers of different materials, and knowing the thickness, density, and specific heat of each layer, how can I calculate the specific heat of the entire panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the layers be indexed by $i$, with each layer having thickness $t_i$, density $\rho_i$, specific heat capacity $C_i$, and all layers having the same area $A$. The mass of each layer is then $m_i=At_i\rho_i$. The specific heat capacity of the entire panel is the weighted average of the $C_i$'s, weighted by the mass of each layer:
$$C=\frac{\sum_im_iC_i}{\sum_jm_j}=\boxed{\frac{\sum_it_i\rho_iC_i}{\sum_jt_j\rho_j}}$$

Answer (score -1):

Specific heat capacity is the heat energy required to raise the temperature of one unit of mass of an object by one unit of temperature.  You need to know $Q_{tot}$ and $m_{tot}$ when the entire object changes by the same temperature, based on $Q$ and $m$ for each piece.